# what file metadata is available in aws - Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

aws Athena allows the user to display the underlying file from which a row is being read, like so:

```
select timestamp, "$path" from table
```

I'm after a comprehensive list of other columns similar to `$path`. In particular I'm looking for a way to query the total size of those files (not the data scanned by the query, but the total size of the files).

Comment: The underlying presto-system has added the `$file_size` and `$file_modified_time` pseudo-columns [a while ago](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-319.html) - I can't find information if this is available in the new Athena Release as well, you could try.

Comment: Thanks @Maurice, Athena is based on presto 0.217, so I guess those aren't available.

Comment: In presto we have: https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#special-columns - but not working in Athena yet (most regions have 0.172)

Answer (score 1):

AWS released Athena engine version 3 last month and I can see that it supports the hidden columns `$file_size` and `$file_modified_time`. But I couldn't find it advertised in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference-0003.html).

Comment: I just tried it with SELECT max($file_modified_time) FROM <my_table>; on AWS Athena 3. It works. Yep, those things are not mentioned in AWS Athena doc.

Answer (score 0):

After some issues here and there i would recommend using:

```
select * from "<table_name>$files"
```